# Как отправить несколько сообщений клиенту подряд(android)

Tags: java, android

У меня есть функция для отправки сообщений:

```
private void sendMessage(final byte[] message) {
    try {
        if (!tempClientSocket.isClosed()) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    PrintWriter out = null;
                    try {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e){
                            showMessage("not sleep2", Color.RED);

                        }
                            DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(tempClientSocket.getOutputStream());

                            dOut.write(message);           // write the message
                            dOut.flush();        // write the message
                            dOut.close();
                            showMessage("TA send mess!", Color.RED);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){
                            showMessage("not sleep3", Color.RED);
                        }
                        if (!tempClientSocket.isClosed()){
                            if (message != null){
                                showMessage("TA send mess!", Color.RED);
                            }
                            else{
                                showMessage("message null", Color.RED);
                            }
                            showMessage("Ta Disconnected", Color.RED);
                            tempClientSocket.close();
                        }
                        else{
                            showMessage("socket close", Color.RED);
                        }
                        //showMessage("TA send mess!", greenColor);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        showMessage("not sleep", Color.RED);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Но проблема в том, что сокет закрывается после отправки первого сообщения. Можно ли отправить сразу несколько и с задержкой в 100 мл

Comment: @Valeriy Я писал фор и помещал туда промежуток от DataOutputStream до dOut.close, во время отправки второго сообщения, мне возвращался IOException, то есть до tempClientSocket.close(); код даже не дошел

Comment: @Valeriy, она попадает, но это не меняет ситуацию

Comment: Хорошо, пойдём от противного, лог ошибки не помешает в вопросе.